# Camel-ahc-ws netty runtime exception

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, apache-camel

Using the following dependencies

```
compile('org.apache.camel:camel-jackson:2.18.0')
compile('org.apache.camel:camel-metrics:2.18.0')
compile('org.apache.camel:camel-spring-boot-starter:2.18.0')
compile('org.apache.camel:camel-spring-redis:2.18.0')
compile('org.apache.camel:camel-stream:2.18.0')
compile('org.apache.camel:camel-ahc-ws:2.18.0')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator')
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
```

And the following ahc-ws definition in Spring Boot

```
.........
.multicast()
.parallelProcessing()

.pipeline()
.marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
.convertBodyTo(String.class)  // Avoids string serialization issues in websocket component.
.to("ahc-ws://localhost:8080/votes?sendToAll=true")
.end()
.........
```

At runtime I get the following error when publishing to this sink

```
2016-10-25 11:41:45.689  INFO 1864 --- [ #7 - Multicast] o.a.camel.component.ahc.ws.WsEndpoint    : Reconnecting websocket: ws://localhost:8080/votes?sendToAll=true
2016-10-25 11:41:45.777 ERROR 1864 --- [ #7 - Multicast] o.a.camel.processor.DefaultErrorHandler  : Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-singram-mint172-42019-1477410101007-0-56 on ExchangeId: ID-singram-mint172-42019-1477410101007-0-59). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.ConnectException: io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelId.newInstance()Lio/netty/channel/DefaultChannelId;

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.ConnectException: io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelId.newInstance()Lio/netty/channel/DefaultChannelId;
        at org.asynchttpclient.netty.NettyResponseFuture.abort(NettyResponseFuture.java:239) ~[async-http-client-2.0.15.jar:na]
        at org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyConnectListener.onFailure(NettyConnectListener.java:162) ~[async-http-client-2.0.15.jar:na]
        at org.asynchttpclient.netty.request.NettyChannelConnector$1.onFailure(NettyChannelConnector.java:103) ~[async-http-client-2.0.15.jar:na]
        at org.asynchttpclient.netty.SimpleChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(SimpleChannelFutureListener.java:28) ~[async-http-client-2.0.15.jar:na]
        at org.asynchttpclient.netty.SimpleChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(SimpleChannelFutureListener.java:20) ~[async-http-client-2.0.15.jar:na]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:514) ~[netty-all-4.1.5.Final.jar:4.1.5.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:488) ~[netty-all-4.1.5.Final.jar:4.1.5.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.access$000(DefaultPromise.java:34) ~[netty-all-4.1.5.Final.jar:4.1.5.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise$1.run(DefaultPromise.java:438) ~[netty-all-4.1.5.Final.jar:4.1.5.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.GlobalEventExecutor$TaskRunner.run(GlobalEventExecutor.java:233) ~[netty-all-4.1.5.Final.jar:4.1.5.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144) ~[netty-all-4.1.5.Final.jar:4.1.5.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_91] Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelId.newInstance()Lio/netty/channel/DefaultChannelId;
        at org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyConnectListener.onFailure(NettyConnectListener.java:160) ~[async-http-client-2.0.15.jar:na]
        ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelId.newInstance()Lio/netty/channel/DefaultChannelId;
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.newId(AbstractChannel.java:107) ~[netty-all-4.1.5.Final.jar:4.1.5.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.<init>(AbstractChannel.java:79) ~[netty-all-4.1.5.Final.jar:4.1.5.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel.<init>(AbstractNioChannel.java:84) ~[netty-all-4.1.5.Final.jar:4.1.5.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel.<init>(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:54) ~[netty-all-4.1.5.Final.jar:4.1.5.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.<init>(NioSocketChannel.java:98) ~[netty-all-4.1.5.Final.jar:4.1.5.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.<init>(NioSocketChannel.java:88) ~[netty-all-4.1.5.Final.jar:4.1.5.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.<init>(NioSocketChannel.java:81) ~[netty-all-4.1.5.Final.jar:4.1.5.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.<init>(NioSocketChannel.java:74) ~[netty-all-4.1.5.Final.jar:4.1.5.Final]
        at org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NioSocketChannelFactory.newChannel(NioSocketChannelFactory.java:25) ~[async-http-client-2.0.15.jar:na]
        at org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NioSocketChannelFactory.newChannel(NioSocketChannelFactory.java:19) ~[async-http-client-2.0.15.jar:na]
        at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap.initAndRegister(AbstractBootstrap.java:319) ~[netty-all-4.1.5.Final.jar:4.1.5.Final]
        at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.doResolveAndConnect(Bootstrap.java:163) ~[netty-all-4.1.5.Final.jar:4.1.5.Final]
        at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.connect(Bootstrap.java:156) ~[netty-all-4.1.5.Final.jar:4.1.5.Final]
```

Any thoughts on what's going on/missing?

I did notice that the dependency tree is a little odd in that netty-all (see bottom) is 4.1.5 and all other netty dependencies are 4.0.41.  This was generated with 'gradle dependencies'

```
+--- org.apache.camel:camel-ahc-ws:2.18.0
|    +--- org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.18.0 (*)
|    \--- org.apache.camel:camel-ahc:2.18.0
|         +--- org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.18.0 (*)
|         +--- org.asynchttpclient:async-http-client:2.0.15
|         |    +--- org.asynchttpclient:async-http-client-netty-utils:2.0.15
|         |    |    +--- io.netty:netty-buffer:4.0.41.Final
|         |    |    |    \--- io.netty:netty-common:4.0.41.Final
|         |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21
|         |    +--- io.netty:netty-codec-http:4.0.41.Final
|         |    |    +--- io.netty:netty-codec:4.0.41.Final
|         |    |    |    \--- io.netty:netty-transport:4.0.41.Final
|         |    |    |         \--- io.netty:netty-buffer:4.0.41.Final (*)
|         |    |    \--- io.netty:netty-handler:4.0.41.Final
|         |    |         +--- io.netty:netty-buffer:4.0.41.Final (*)
|         |    |         +--- io.netty:netty-transport:4.0.41.Final (*)
|         |    |         \--- io.netty:netty-codec:4.0.41.Final (*)
|         |    +--- io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:4.0.41.Final
|         |    |    +--- io.netty:netty-common:4.0.41.Final
|         |    |    +--- io.netty:netty-buffer:4.0.41.Final (*)
|         |    |    \--- io.netty:netty-transport:4.0.41.Final (*)
|         |    +--- org.asynchttpclient:netty-resolver-dns:2.0.15
|         |    |    +--- org.asynchttpclient:netty-resolver:2.0.15
|         |    |    |    +--- io.netty:netty-common:4.0.41.Final
|         |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21
|         |    |    +--- org.asynchttpclient:netty-codec-dns:2.0.15
|         |    |    |    +--- io.netty:netty-codec:4.0.41.Final (*)
|         |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21
|         |    |    +--- io.netty:netty-transport:4.0.41.Final (*)
|         |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21
|         |    +--- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.0
|         |    +--- com.typesafe.netty:netty-reactive-streams:1.0.7
|         |    |    +--- io.netty:netty-handler:4.0.39.Final -> 4.0.41.Final (*)
|         |    |    \--- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.0
|         |    +--- org.javassist:javassist:3.20.0-GA
|         |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21
|         \--- io.netty:netty-all:4.1.5.Final
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to exclude netty-all 4.1.5 and include netty-all 4.0.41.Final instead.
This helped my to get past these errors.

And I'm going to open a defect at camel for this, because I believe you are correct sir: it is indeed an "odd" dependency tree :)

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-10465